# Zlib deflate/inflate proper initialization

Tags: compression, zlib, deflate

While using zlib in a "pedantic" way, I have stumbled across a couple inconsistencies I'd like to clear for myself.

For `inflateInit()`, the manual states:

> ... The fields `next_in`, `avail_in`, `zalloc`, `zfree` and `opaque` must be initialized before by the caller.

yet in the next paragraph:

> ... So `next_in`, and `avail_in`, `next_out`, and `avail_out` are unused and unchanged.

In other words, the manual requires `next_in` and `avail_in` to be initialized prior to calling `inflateInit()`, but at the same time, it states that they won't be used anyway. Why is that? In my case, I tried to leave them both uninitialized and initialized to zero with no problems until the moment real preparations are made before a call to `deflate()`. But strictly speaking, it is in violation of the manual unless "must be initialized" means I can initialize them to zeros. But why bother then?

Note that there is no such requirement for `deflateInit()`:

> ... The fields `zalloc`, `zfree` and `opaque` must be initialized before by the caller.

Why the asymmetry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a thought that `inflateInit()` could make use of information in the compressed data header for initialization. So the interface requirement was that `next_in` and `avail_in` be initialized. As the description notes, using the phrases "current version" and "current implementation", such initialization is deferred to the calls of the `inflate()`. A future version of zlib might do something different. (Though I doubt it will.)

There is no plausible benefit to providing input data to `deflateInit()`, hence the asymmetry.

Comment: Thank you, Mark, for chiming in! :-) I do hope a future version will not brake this because in cases where a compressor is prepared to receive messages long before they start to arrive, an explicit step will be required to defer `deflateInit()`.

Comment: ...will not _break_ this...